# Termination called after throwing an instance 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++

Their is a runtime error of 'out_of_range'. It works when i use i>0, but my first character does not get added to my string if i do so.

```
int main(){

string str;
string strR;
short count {0};

getline(cin,str);

int n=str.length();

for(size_t i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
strR.push_back(str.at(i));


    if(str==strR)
    cout<<"Yes\n";
    else
    cout<<"No\n";

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

For `i` of type `size_t`, the condition `i >= 0` is always true. After `i` being zero, *negative overflow* occurs and `i` becomes some large number. `str.at(i)` then naturally throws.

Very simple correction:

```
for (size_t i = n; i > 0; i--)
   strR.push_back(str.at(i - 1));
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a signed type for `i`, such as `int`. However, this may then broke for very large strings. I wouldn't use it in production code.

---

BTW, to check whether a string is a palindrome, you don't need to copy it. Simpler and faster would be just iterating over the half of the string and compare corresponding characters from the second half.